# How to load Rational Rhapsody plugin with help of maven/gradle instead of .hep file

Tags: maven, gradle, plugins, jar, rhapsody

At the moment I am able to load the custom developed plugins in rhapsody using .hep file.

But now I want to deploy those plugins in central repository and from needs to be download, load them in rhapsody instead of .hep file

Now my question is : can we download with help of maven/gradle and load them in rhapsody from any repository ? If yes, Can somebody please help me about how to do that ?

Comment: I’m not understanding your third paragraph. Can reword please?

Comment: bjenkins001 : Is rhapsody has a way to get plugins directly from a Maven/Ivy repo directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Vinod,  I think the easiest way to do this is to create a .cmd windows script that you call instead of Rhapsody.exe directly and in THAT script, you would invoke maven/gradle to pull down the .jar plugins you need and drop them into the appropriate directories that the your .sbs profiles in your project are tied to, after which the .cmd script would launch rhapsody.exe.